# Theta notation for polynomial - Fundamental Algorithms

Tags: algorithm, big-o

What is the Theta notation for the below function:

> f(n) = (n + 1)/(n^2 + 2)

Any suggestion would be great!!!

Comment: The Θ notation is not unique. You do have (n+1)/(n²+2)=Θ((n+1)/(n²+2)) !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression for large `n` values (`n → ∞`) is asymptotically equivalent to `1/n`

To check that `f(n)` is equivalent to `g(n)`, we have to show that limit of their ratio is constant:

```
f(n) / (1/n)  = n*(n+1)/(n^2 + 2) = (n^2 + n)/(n^2 + 2) = 
               n^2/(n^2 + 2) + n/(n^2 + 2) = 
               (n^2 + 2)/(n^2 + 2) - 2/(n^2 + 2) + n/(n^2 + 2) = 
               1  - 2/(n^2 + 2) + n/(n^2 + 2)
```

so

```
limit(f(n)/(1/n))[n → ∞] = 1 - 0 + 0 = 1
```

and `f(n)` is asymptotically equivalent to `1/n`

Comment: shouldn't the limit of this expression for (n → ∞) be 0? how did you get 1/n could you please explain.

Comment: @grooot He meant that f(n) is [asymptotically equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis) to 1/n.

Comment: @Olivier Thanks, limit is definitely wrong term here